# Combine two filter conditions inside flatmap

Tags: javascript

I have a filter method that looks like this

```
Object.values(state.storeLayout.items).flatMap((level) => 
   level.poi?.filter((x) => 
      (x.guid === guid)) ?? []).map((poi) => poi.coordinate)
```

However I also want to do:

```
Object.values(state.storeLayout.items).flatMap((level) => 
   level.portals?.filter((x) => 
      (x.guid === guid)) ?? []).map((poi) => poi.coordinate)
```

My question how is how I can concat the two filter methods

```
 level.portals?.filter((x) => 
      (x.guid === guid)) ?? [])

 level.poi?.filter((x) => 
      (x.guid === guid)) ?? [])
```

inside flatMap, so that I only have one function

so basically something like this

```
Object.values(state.storeLayout.items).flatMap((level) => 
   level.poi?.filter((x) => 
      (x.guid === guid)
  && 
 level.portal?.filter((x) => 
      (x.guid === guid)
) ?? []).map((poi) => poi.coordinate)
```

Comment: Could you write desired input and output?

Comment: The `portal` filter returns a list of portals, which have nothing to do with `poi`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
Object.values(state.storeLayout.items).flatMap((level) => {
   let tmpLevel = {...level}
   tmpLevel.portal = tmpLevel.portal?.filter((x) => (x.guid === guid) ?? []
   tmpLevel.poi = tmpLevel.poi?.filter((x) => (x.guid === guid)) ?? []

   return tmpLevel
} ?? []).map((poi) => poi.coordinate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @KiraLT mentioned it would be easier if you provided the desired input and output but one way you can handle this is by using reduce.

Background:

- In JS, functions are first-class, which means they can be passed around as arguments to other functions. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/First-class_Function)
- You can destructure values or properties from objects (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- Reduce "walks through the array element-by-element, at each step adding the current array value to the result from the previous step (this result is the running sum of all the previous steps) — until there are no more elements to add." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) In this case we can set an array of callback fns and the initial value the param that should be passed to your first fn.
- flatMap is basically map, then flat. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

This is probably ~ same performance as your fn ^, so take it with a grain of salt.

```
  function flatMapStoreItems() {
    const guid = W/E

    
    function filterPortals(items) {
      return items.portals?.filter(({ guid: itemGuid }) => itemGuid == guid ?? [])
    }

    function filterPoi(items) {
      return items.poi?.filter(({ guid: itemGuid }) => itemGuid == guid ?? [])
    }

    function mapCoordinates(items) {
      return items.map(({ coordinate }) => coordinate)
    }

    function flat(items) {
      return items.flat();
    }

    return [filterPortals, filterPoi, mapCoordinates, flat].reduce((fn), Object.values(state.storeLayout.items))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This returns the desired result:

```
Object.values(state.storeLayout.items).flatMap((level) => {
   let tmpLevel = {...level}
   tmpLevel.portal = tmpLevel.portal?.filter((x) => (x.guid === guid) ?? []
   tmpLevel.poi = tmpLevel.poi?.filter((x) => (x.guid === guid)) ?? []

   return tmpLevel.poi.concat(tmpLevel.portals)
} ?? []).map((poi) => poi.coordinate)
```

Thanks everyone for reading and posting answers to help me out!